# Marker Based Augmented Reality Model Viewer using Android

Tags: java, android

Anyone knows about Marker Based Augmented Reality using in Android. Currently I set all my setup of camera in android 2.2. And now searching the, How to use Augmented Reality. Any knows about this. Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [AndAR](http://code.google.com/p/andar/)

You can go through the sample code given in the repository.

You can also use the book [Pro Android Augmented Reality](http://www.apress.com/9781430239451).

(In the interest of full disclosure, I wrote that book).

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply.
"Pro Android Augmented Reality" Book will be release on July 11. But Alpha Book is released. Is that have all stuff about my requirements?